# Issues with ng-required directive angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want my input to be required based on condition.

```
      <input type="text" custom-directive ng-required="isRequired" />
```

I have defined property isRequired as boolean false. Required functionality works fine according to the isRequired property. But inside the custom directive i am getting $attrs.required as true for all scenarios.

```
      module.directive('customDirective', function () {
          var link = function ($scope, $el, $attrs, $controllers) {
              $scope.required = $attrs.required;
          }

          return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: link
          };
      });
```

Thanks

Comment: What's going on with your code...? You weren't very clear.

Comment: Change `$scope.required` to `$scope.isRequired`

Comment: @rtcherry. Yes managed to resolve using $observe itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unable to explain why `$scope.required` would be true in this case (perhaps you are setting it to `true` somewhere else and should be using a child or isolation scope?)...  I would expect it to be `undefined` based on what you have provided.  The other possibility is that you have multiple elements with this directive in the same scope and one of them is setting that value to true for all of them.

By replacing your `$scope.required = $attrs.required;` line with

```
$attrs.$observe('required', function(value) {
    $scope.required = value;
});
```

it should properly pick up the value of the `required` attribute (and when it changes!).

If you have that directive being applied to multiple elements in the same scope you should use a child scope.  All you need to do is add `scope: true` to the object returned by your directive.

If this does not work, please post more of your application's code.

Comment: Thanks. I have a very simple directive and i have checked it i am not setting it to true anywhere. Yes its true using observe i can do that. But was wondering why the attrs.required value is coming as true.

Comment: @Venkat Could you please post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [plunker](http://plnkr.co) that shows the problem, or at least show some more HTML and the AngularJS controller.

Comment: Thank you so much rtcherry! I spent hours on this. Couldn't find documentation on why $watch was not correct for watching 'required' attribute. Which could dynamically be changed via ngRequired.